# serializing Eigen's Matrix using boost.serialization

Tags: derived-class, boost-serialization, eigen

I'm trying to serialize Eigen's matrix. So that I can serialize a more complex object.
I'm using Matrix as a base class and include the serialization in the derived class. I'm confused on how to address Matrix.data(), which returns a c-style array (if i'm correct).
This is my attempt:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

template < class TEigenMatrix>
class VariableType : public TEigenMatrix {
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      ar & this.data();
  }
public:
};
```

I would like to use it as a "wrapper" :

```
VariableType<Matrix<double,3,1>> serializableVector;
```

in place of

```
Matrix<double,3,1> vector;
```

Comment: for serialization, I used http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By placing the following free function into your compilation unit, you effectively make Boost.Serialization aware of how to serialize Eigen types:

```
namespace boost
{
    template<class Archive, typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
    inline void serialize(
        Archive & ar, 
        Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> & t, 
        const unsigned int file_version
    ) 
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
            ar & t.data()[i];
    }
}
```

In the example you gave, you should then be able to do (untested):

```
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & *this;
}
```

Have a look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618789/672634) on serialization of Eigen types using Boost.Serialization for a more detailed example.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to write the serialization for `Eigen::DenseBase`? I think in this way one could also serialize `Eigen::Array` with the same code, see: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Answer (score 9):

Since Matrix in Eigen are dense, so you can replace the for-loop in Jakob's answer with [make_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays) as:

> ar & boost::serialization::make_array(t.data(), t.size());

I made a more detailed answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23407209/1686769