# boost serialize Eigen MatrixXd to XML

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, xml-serialization, eigen

I am trying to serialize an Eigen matrix using boost serialization. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851126/serializing-eigens-matrix-using-boost-serialization) and tried to use the solution, however I have strange compiler errrors.

I have a `shared_ptr` to a `MatrixXd` and try and serialize it as follows:

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "utils.hpp"
    boost::shared_ptr<std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> > > class_to_inv_cov_mat;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(class_to_inv_cov_mat);
    }
```

I also have utils.hpp which includes this:

```
namespace boost {

template<class Archive, typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
   inline void serialize(
       Archive & ar, 
       Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> & t, 
       const unsigned int file_version
   ) 
   {
       for(size_t i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
           ar & t.data()[i];
   }
}
```

When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:148:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, const void*) const [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive, T = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]’
../src/Main.cpp:357:1:   instantiated from here

/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_oarchive.hpp:92:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ boost::serialization::is_wrapper<const double>::************)’
```

I have no idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

needed to change the code in utils to contain `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` i.e.

namespace boost {

template
   inline void serialize(
       Archive & ar, 
       Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> & t, 
       const unsigned int file_version
   ) 
   {
       for(size_t i=0; i